# "Can't open /scripts/casper"

Tags: live-usb, initramfs, persistence

After attempting to upgrade from xenial to yakkety on a Live USB, I encountered an error upon attempting to reboot. During the boot, there is a kernel panic, evidently caused by the fact that `/init` is unable to open `/scripts/casper`

The following are the three lines before the kernel panic and the first line of the kernel panic

```
Begin: Loading essential drivers ... done.
Begin: Running /scripts/init-premount ... done
Begin: Mounting root file system ... /init: .: line 257: can't open '/scripts/casper'
[   34.941779] Kernel panic - not syncing: Attempted to kill init! exitcode=0x00000200
```

I had guessed at first that maybe the `/scripts/casper/` file was missing in `/usr/share/initramfs-tools/scripts/` in the squashfs, but it seems to be there, and with normal permissions.

What could be the cause of this problem, and how could one fix it?

Comment: hmmm... what does line 257 say?

Comment: @Zanna Line 257 of `init` is `. /scripts/${BOOT}`, which I think is default.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try to 'do-release-upgrade' a persistent live USB drive to the next Ubuntu release?

I don't think it will work. You can ***keep (backup and later restore) the home directory***, best stored in a **home-rw** partition (or file), but you should remove all other directories and files (except upper/home and upper/lost+found) from the **casper-rw** partition (or file), and start using the iso file from the new Ubuntu release.

This means that you can keep your personal files, program settings and tweaks, but you must reinstall the programs that you added.

-o-

It is possible to 'do-release-upgrade' a system that is installed in a USB drive (installed like into an internal drive, but to a USB drive).

The problems and solutions should be the same or similar as for a normal installed system.

Comment: Yes, I tried a `do-release-upgrade` on the persistent live USB. After two retries and two months of waiting on the potato that was trying to do the `do-release-upgrade`, I can pretty much confirm that `do-release-upgrade` is not normally possible on a persistent Live USB.